# Scraping or caching Geoserver Web Feature Server (NG) data

Tags: geoserver, wfs

We rely on a third-party WFS service which is quite unstable, and sometimes it's offline for days at end. We would therefore like to use a local GeoServer, together with the Web Feature Server (NG) store, to mirror and cache the upstream service. This works in principle, and we can serve the data locally. But when the upstream service goes down, so does the local service. Is there any way of scraping and caching a remote WFS service with GoeServer, to improve availability?

(As a side note, we can download the raw WFS Shape data, but it involves e-mail and a SMS-service, and is not easily automated. The WFS data is updated regularly, but not predictably).

Comment: Maybe not the answer to your question but I use geopandas to download all features from a WFS service every night as csv files by sending request with bounding boxes. I can show you an example if you want to

Comment: Thanks! That's actually a pretty good solution,and easy enough to automate fully. I'll look into it.